# Jest mockImplementation is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocking

I have this simplified Jest test:

```
import login from "../../src/controller/auth/login";
import findUserByEmail from "../../src/api/db/find-user-by-email";

jest.mock("../../src/api/db/find-user-by-email");
const mockedfindUserByEmail = findUserByEmail as jest.Mocked<typeof findUserByEmail>;

describe("Login API", () => {
  test('should return 401', async () => {

    const req = {
      email: "email@domain.com",
      password: "password"
    };

    mockedfindUserByEmail.mockImplementation(async () => false)

    expect(await login(req).status).toBe(401);
  });
});
```

I got this mock from the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockresolvedvalueoncevalue). When I don't mock the test works fine because the `login` module connects to the database. But when I use the above mock I get:

```
TypeError: findUserByEmail.mockImplementation is not a function
```

Can you help?

The find-user-by-email file:

```
import { User } from "../../entities/main/user";
const db: any = require("../../db/models");

export default async (email: string)
  : Promise<User> => {
  return await db.user.findOne({
    where: { email },
    raw: true,
  });
};
```

Comment: Maybe `../../src/api/db/find-user-by-email` doesn't have a default export ?

Comment: @Teneff Thanks! But it does have default export. I edited the question - added its code.

Comment: it looks fine, probably you should try to make a reproducible example. Or if it's a typescript error you should cast it `findUserByEmail as jest.Mocked<typeof findUserByEmail>`

Comment: @Teneff How exactly I should do that? If it should be the way I just updated the question, still I'm getting the Typescript error `Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type 'Mocked<(email: string) => Promise<User>>'.`

Comment: try with `findUserByEmail as jest.Mocked<typeof import('../../src/api/db/find-user-by-email')>`

Comment: @Teneff OK, I figured my mistake. I shouldn't mock `find-user-by-email`. I should mock the DB module itself (the one imported into find-user-by-email in the second line). I mocked it and the test worked without to access the DB. Thanks for trying to help!